# Horizontal scroll in chrome despite overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css

http://settlin.in

Both `html` and `body` tags have `overflow-x:hidden`. It works as expected in Firefox. But in Chrome (`Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)`), I am able to scroll horizontally (though the scrollbars are invisible).

How can I fix this? Is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: I have notticed that if your remove the "height: 100%" on body, it works as expected. Did you really need that css rule?

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk it does not work for me with height: 100% removed. I don't expect it too.
The height is needed for a few other pages on the website, where the desktop version does not have a vertical scroll.

Comment: I have created a small avi with the behaviour on my side. As you can notice, when I remove the css rule, it works as expected. I have noticed that removing the rule, makes the yellow button changes its position. Maybe it will give you some clues of what's going on:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36289192/capture.avi

Comment: Not sure. I am doing the same but it does not work for me. What is your chrome version?

Comment: Versión 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit)